# "The subscription will not auto renew" message is shown in the app while purchasing subscription and auto renew not working

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am getting the message "The subscription will not auto-renew" while purchasing the subscription. And after the purchase has been completed the subscription is not auto renewing. Everything is properly set up and I am using the sandbox environment currently for testing the in-app purchase. Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
In order to help you it would be useful to know the framework you are using to develop your app as well as the relevant code. Otherwise, we have no way to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your profile, I see you are from India.

A few months ago, Google has announced that it would pause new signups of auto-renewing subscriptions for users in India:

> Subscriptions will continue to be available as single access passes that provide users a single billing period of access (eg. 1-month access). At the end of the billing duration, Google says users will need to sign up again in order to continue their subscription.

source: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-suspend-free-trials-auto-renewing-subscriptions/

So I think it's normal and you should test on another country if you want your auto-renewable subscription to actually renew ^^

Comment: @pankaj-verna, if my answer helped you, could you marked it as resolved to help other users know they can look at it, please?

Comment: Yes sure, Thanks